# Using Gud Achis on a Lechi

Tags: halacha, eruv-chatzerot, mechitza-partition

Do we apply Gud Achis to the Lechi's of an eruv, or only Gud Asik? 
Let me explain: On one side there is a proper Lechi that goes from the ground up to the string (i.e. the Koreh), the string streches out towards a wall, and where the string meets the wall, right under the string I placed a Lechi that is attached to the wall, is ten Tefochim, but ends a few feet above the ground. Can we apply Gud Achis and consider the second Lechi to be Kosher?

Comment: Technically it's probably more correct to refer to the string as a kaneh not a koreh. A koreh needs to be a tefach wide.

Comment: Is the question whether the *lechi* is kosher, or whether it's called a Tzuras HaPesach?

Comment: @DonielF What's the difference? 'We' generally don't use the Kulot of Mavoi nowadays.

Comment: @DoubleAA I don't know about you, but my community's eruv is made of tzuros hapesach. If it's a question on the lechi, why would it matter if the second lechi is kosher since there's another lechi?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The Lechi needs to reach to within 3 Tefachim of the ground. (Eruvin 14b, ShA OC 363:10)

Answer (score 0):

Your case sounds like Figure 5-39 seen on page 101 in The Laws Of Eruv.

The authors there say Reb Moshe Feinstein was concerned it is a tzuras hapesach min hatzad, and Rav Heineman told them in the name of Reb Aharon Kotler that it is not a problem.
[image]

This issue here is not really with gud achis though. Gud achis as applied to an actual wall is discussed in Shulchan Aruch O'Ch 355.

The real issue here is how much does the Lechi have to be completely and directly under the cross section. As noted above, this is a machlokes.